# Invalid gemspec because of the date format in specification

Tags: rubygems, bundler, ruby-1.9, ruby-1.9.2

When I include a gem that I made, thanks to Bundler (version 1.0.12), in a Gemfile and then I try to bundle or to rake just like that:

`$ rake`

I've got this error message:

```
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/zagzag/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@foobar/specifications/myplugin-1.0.0.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-04-21 00:00:00.000000000Z"
```

I'm on the last Mac OS X (10.6.4), with:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin10.4.0]
```

and:

```
$ gem -v
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/zagzag/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@foobar/specifications/myplugin-1.0.0.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-04-21 00:00:00.000000000Z"
1.7.2
```

I really don't see how to solve this issue.  Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: I'm getting these errors constantly now!!! How did you fix? Two answers thus far aren't helpful...

Comment: That one everyone suggested, is read only file. How can I change it?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Here is the way I fix the "invalid date format in specification" error:

1.) Go to the specifications folder located at:

`/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications/`

2.) Find the spec that is causing the problem.

3.) Change `s.date = %q{2011-05-21 00:00:00.000000000Z}` to `s.date = %q{2011-05-21}`

That's a WIN for me! Good Luck

Comment: Worked a treat, this was doing my head in!

Comment: Worked for me! I was on Windows XP with Ruby 1.8 installed. The em.websocket-0.3.2.gemspec was throwing this error for me when trying to use 'livereload' (http://livereload.com/).

Comment: Worked for me too, on linux on chronic 1.6.4

Comment: It fixes the problem for one gem, but following installed gems could cause this error again.

Comment: this is driving me mad... am I supposed to change the gemspec of 50 3rd party gems? why haven't they updated the gemspecs, a year has passed..

Comment: Worked for me on mac Lion 10.7

Answer (score 60):

Here is the command to fix this for all your gems:

```
perl -p -i -e 's/ 00:00:00.000000000Z//' ~/gems/specifications/*.gemspec
```

It converts `s.date = %q{2011-05-21 00:00:00.000000000Z}` to `s.date = %q{2011-05-21}` and should fix your issue.

Comment: Nice trick to make a quick backup before doing this: `git init . && git commit -am "backup`

Comment: Why trying to change the date format, it says I don't have permission to do so. What to do?

Comment: @chhantyal You need to run it as sudo then.

Thank you so much for this! Saved me soo much time.

Answer (score 21):

**Please notice the comment from Damian Nowak. These commands do possibly mess up your rubygems!**

On Ubuntu 11.10 the following solved this error:

```
sudo gem install rubygems-update
sudo update_rubygems
```

The following may work on some systems but not on Debian based:

```
sudo gem update --system
```

Comment: Great, also works with the final version of oneiric. But this seems to clean out all manually installed gems.

Comment: Do NOT use it. It messed my rubygems. I had to rm -rf lots of stuff and revert to original rubygems from the repo. Either install rubygems totally manually or use a provided rubygems by Ubuntu. Alternatively, you may look for current rubygems in PPA. (I wish I could undo my +1 that was made about a month ago)

Comment: @DamianNowak Sorry to hear this. I added a warning to the answer!

Answer (score 14):

You may upgraded your `gem`. To fix this you can edit the `gemspec`file directly -
from

```
2011-04-21 00:00:00.000000000Z
```

to

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

Or
upgrade your rails also

```
sudo gem update rails
```

It will fix the issue.

Comment: @Meltemi it will be under `specifications` directory
this is my `specifications` directory path - `/home/sayuj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/specifications/`

Comment: +1 for updating rails - it does fix the issue, though it throws the same warnings in the beginning, it installs correctly and the problem no longer occurs.

Answer (score 6):

Don't specify the time... just the date. `2011-04-21` should work fine.

Comment: Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name        = "myplugin"
  s.version     = "1.0.0"
  s.platform    = Gem::Platform::RUBY
  s.authors     = ["..."]
  s.email       = ["..."]
  s.homepage    = "http://..."
  s.summary     = %q{...}
  s.description = %q{...}

  s.rubyforge_project = "myplugin"

  s.files         = `git ls-files`.split("\n")
  s.test_files    = `git ls-files -- {test,spec,features}/*`.split("\n")
  s.require_paths = ["lib"]
end

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree with you, but I don't used any date or datetime in the myplugin.gemspec file. The Gem was auto-generated by Bundler. I think this issue could be because of Bundler or RVM... It's strange.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue. It looks like a bug in rubygems. Here's the commit that fixed it: https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/commit/21cccd55b823848c5e941093a615b0fdd6cd8bc7

You need to update rubygems and bundler to the latest versions. If you are still having issues after that, then you may need to remove and then reinstall any gems that are giving you problems.

Comment: Well, except Redmine uses its own 2.3.11 version of Rails, Rails 2.3.11 fails with RubyGems >= 1.7.0, and the commit you mention is dated May 19th, 2011, which is post-1.7.0 (April 1st, 2011). Guess in that case you need to edit the spec files.

Answer (score 3):

This is more of a comment to ben hall's answer, but i dont have that privilege yet it seems

gem updates didn't seem to work, im thinking it can't even load the gem because of the bad date format. manually changing the dates was too frustrating to go one by one, so a grep:

```
grep -i *.gemspec -e '.*s\.date.*=.*%q{\(....-..-..\) \(.*Z\)}
```

And for sed:

```
sed -i -e 's/\(.*\)s\.date.*=.*%q{\(....-..-..\) \(.*Z\)}/\1s.date = %q\{\2}/p' ./*.gemspec
```

And at your own risks!!
I'm still a sed newbie, but it worked for me ;)

Answer (score 2):

On my slicehost server the specifications folder was located in a different spot. Here is the path:

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications

The error provided should give the path to the specifications folder.

Answer (score 2):

**The shotgun approach:** Uninstall all gems and rerun bundler.

1. `gem list --no-version | xargs gem uninstall -aIx`
2. `` rm -i `rvm gemdir`/specifications/*.gemspec ``
3. `gem update --system`
4. `gem install bundler`
5. `bundle install`

Comment: If you use a `.rvmrc` file, then be careful running line 2 because gemdir may produce extra output.

Answer (score 1):

(Until the bug fix gets into a stable release of Rubygems) I solved it by reinstalling the same version of any warning-generating gems using the --version switch of the gem command.

Answer (score 1):

As Ben Hall said, you must fix the gemspec file that may change for system to system. To know what file is see what file is tell in the error report, for example:

> Invalid gemspec in
>   [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/svn2git-2.1.2.gemspec]: invalid date
>   format in specification: "2011-12-28 00:00:00.000000000Z"

In this example you must edit "/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/svn2git-2.1.2.gemspec" file and change "2011-12-28 00:00:00.000000000Z" for "2011-12-28" in s.date option.

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem still now. Updating Rubygems solved it fine:

```
gem update --system
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my environment:

```
RubyGems Environment:
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.10
- RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-07-09 patchlevel 290) [x86_64-darwin11.1.0]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@app
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@app/bin
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
  - ruby
  - x86_64-darwin-11
- GEM PATHS:
   - /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@app
   - /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
   - :update_sources => true
   - :verbose => true
   - :benchmark => false
   - :backtrace => false
   - :bulk_threshold => 1000
- REMOTE SOURCES:
   - http://rubygems.org/
```

I finally managed to find a cause / a way to prevent these errors on my system. I just revert to cucumber and cucumber-rails version 1.0.2. Using the latest versions was doing this...

Answer (score 0):

Even if you install the latest version of a gem with a valid date format, make sure to `gem cleanup GEMNAME` afterwards, since `gem` will still complain about the specifications for the older libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling your gems can be the solution in many of these slightly different machine states.

In my case:

```
cd /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/specifications &&
sudo rm -rf *
```

In my case, the other more creative solutions failed.

My issue was getting `Invalid gemspec` when trying to use cocoapods. I ran `gem install cocoapods` again and everything was rosy.