# Heroku problems on Windows 7 (cmd)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I just installed the heroku ruby gem on Windows 7 and received the following error when trying to create a new instance. Have been researching the cause for the past two days with no luck.

```
C:\Users\admin\RubymineProjects\first_app>heroku create
Invalid gemspec in [C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications
/heroku-2.8.5.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-10-05 00:00:
00.000000000Z"
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:926:in `report_ac
tivate_error': Could not find RubyGem heroku (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:244:
in `activate_dep'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:236:
in `activate'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1307
:in `gem'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/bin/heroku:18

C:\Users\admin\RubymineProjects\first_app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try one of the following solutions (if you haven't already) - this isn't specific to Windows:

[Invalid date format specification in gemspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290575/invalid-date-format-specification-in-gemspec)

[invalid date format in specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642494/invalid-date-format-in-specification)

[Invalid gemspec because of the date format in specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771758/invalid-gemspec-because-of-the-date-format-in-specification)

[How to safely fix "invalid date format in specification" for webrobots-0.0.10.gemspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989707/how-to-safely-fix-invalid-date-format-in-specification-for-webrobots-0-0-10-gem)