# Invalid date format specification in gemspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am getting the following error when I try to use gems in windows, and I also referred to 
[this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771758/invalid-gemspec-because-of-the-date-format-in-specification) and updated rubygems and rails. But nothing could solve the problem.

The following is the complete error,

```
    D:\>gem env
Invalid gemspec in [D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications
/tilt-1.3.3.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-08-25 00:00:00
.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications
/execjs-1.2.4.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-08-03 00:00:
00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications
/temple-0.3.3.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-08-26 00:00:
00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications
/guard-0.6.3.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-09-01 00:00:0
0.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications
/guard-livereload-0.3.1.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-09
-01 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications
/rack-cache-1.0.3.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-08-27 00
:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications
/tilt-1.3.3.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-08-25 00:00:00
.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications
/execjs-1.2.4.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-08-03 00:00:
00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications
/temple-0.3.3.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-08-26 00:00:
00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications
/guard-0.6.3.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-09-01 00:00:0
0.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications
/guard-livereload-0.3.1.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-09
-01 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications
/rack-cache-1.0.3.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-08-27 00
:00:00.000000000Z"
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.7.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i386-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - C:/Documents and Settings/jeygokul/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by [upgrading my RubyGems to 1.8.10](http://rubygems.org/pages/download) with

```
gem update --system
```

Edit: You can also try (as suggested by ZeissS)

```
gem install rubygems-update
update_rubygems
```

Comment: I have 1.8.10 and still getting this

Comment: Try running "gem pristine [gemname]" for the gems that are causing those warnings.

Comment: This didn't work for me either - because the "gem update --system" command caused the exact same problem and "gem pristine" did nothing. I had to follow @Romain_Tribes's solution and delete the gemspec files by hand before re-running a gem update

Comment: In my situation, the problem occured after running "gem update" when the Ruby header files weren't in place. After making sure the header files could be found, I ran "gem update" again and everything was ok.

Comment: This isn't a very good option on ubuntu, especially for casual ruby users.

Comment: GaborKomaromi's answer below (or one of the finds.. in the comments) works. This one doesn't.

Answer (score 132):

The ultimate solution is this:

Search "spec" files in your Ruby directory:
**C:\Ruby187\lib\ruby\gems\1.8\specifications**

If a gemspec file contains something like this:
  s.date = %q{2011-10-13 **00:00:00.000000000Z**}
Then delete the **00:00:00.000000000Z** part:
  s.date = %q{2011-10-13}

After saving those gemspec files, the problem is solved.

Comment: This worked for me (ruby 1.8.7 / win7), the other solutions did not

Comment: This worked for my heroku gem that spued:
invalid date format in specification: "2011-11-04 00:00:00.000000000Z

Comment: Worked like a charm on ubuntu with ruby 1.8.7, gem 1.7.2.  Thanks!

Comment: This will remove the string from the specification file: "find . -type f | xargs perl -pi -e 's/ 00:00:00\.000000000Z//'"

Comment: find /var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications -name *.gemspec -type f | xargs perl -pi -e 's/ 00:00:00\.000000000Z//' in Ubuntu

Comment: Update and pristine didn't work for me, but this did (for ree 1.8.7 and rubygems 1.8.15)

Comment: `sed -i 's/ 00:00:00.000000000Z//g' path_to_gemspecs`

Comment: Worked for me on MacOS 10.5.8

Comment: This seems cheap somehow.  It works, don't get me wrong, but won't the next package update undo this change and bring the error back?

Answer (score 46):

None of these solutions worked for me.
To fix it, I removed all the content of the mentioned directory (some/path/to/specification/) then I installed the gems I need (actually, Bundler then bundle install).

Comment: This is simple, quick and effective. Try this before any of the others.

Comment: Only solution that worked for me too. But not sure if this is the right fix.

Comment: This worked for me. It was running gem udpate --system that got me to this problem!

Answer (score 12):

In addition to running `gem update --system` I used `gem install <gem with bad gemspec>` on each of the item gem env reported as bad.  This cleaned up the errors on my machine.

Comment: You can reinstall with "gem pristine [gemname]" or do a "gem pristine --all" to reinstall the gems from the cache without re-downloading them.

Answer (score 10):

As Michael said in the comment:

```
gem pristine --all
```

Answer (score 6):

Had the same problem when trying to install a GEM on Ubuntu 11.10.

```
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/svn2git-2.1.2.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-12-28 00:00:00.000000000Z"
```

The above options did not work for me. `gem env` reported the following:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.7.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-linux]
```

So I presumed this problem was due to the fact I required a newer version of RubyGems installed.

Issuing `gem update --system` yeilded the following warning:

```
ERROR:  gem update --system is disabled on Debian, because it will overwrite the content of the rubygems Debian package, and might break your Debian system in subtle ways. The Debian-supported way to update rubygems is through apt-get, using Debian official repositories.
If you really know what you are doing, you can still update rubygems by setting the REALLY_GEM_UPDATE_SYSTEM environment variable, but please remember that this is completely unsupported by Debian.
```

However I was finally able to update `rubygems` to 1.8.15 by issuing:

```
sudo gem install rubygems-update && update_rubygems
```

Everything worked after that, good luck! :)

Comment: For me on Ubuntu, it took ``sudo apt-get purge rubygems`` followed by ``sudo apt-get install rubygems`` and then installing all the gems again. Awkward, but at least it worked :P (the above did not work for me)

Answer (score 3):

Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/chronic-0.6.4.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-09-09 00:00:00.000000000Z"

The simple fix to such kind of problem is to navigate to the file.. for eg.

Step 1. cd /var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications 
step 2. open the file(chronic-0.6.4.gemspec) in editor of ur choice... (gedit chronic-0.6.4.gemspec) 
step 3. change the s.date = %q{2011-10-13 00:00:00.000000000Z} to s.date = %q{2011-10-13}

Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem on my ubuntu after upgrading to 10.10. None of the above worked for me. I had to install the update_rubygems script from http://rubygems.org/pages/download and run it once. Afterwords everything worked.

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed this issue 'invalid date formate specification' by, changing the corresponding line in D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications/tilt-1.3.3.gemspec by putting 
 s.date =Time.now
instead of s.date = "2011-08-25 00:00:00.000000000Z"
The same can be use the other files too.

Answer (score 2):

I've too many gems to fix one by one, and try both `update_rubygems` and `gem pristine --all` still no luck.

So I use `rvm clear gemset` to remove all gems with wrong gemspec.
Execute `bundle install` to reinstall all the gems, and Viola!

Comment: `Unrecognized command line argument: 'clear' ( see: 'rvm usage' )`

Comment: `rvm gemset empty your_gemset_name_or_global`

Answer (score 2):

```
cd vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.x/specifications
sed -i 's/ 00\:00\:00.000000000Z//g' *
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved by running `gem update --system` then `gem update`.

Comment: worked for me, i just got that error after doing gem update --system, most of them went away after gem update. for others i removed the gemspec file.

Answer (score 1):

The various solutions noted in these answers did not work for me. What did work was re-installing the specific versions of the offending gem's. In your case that would of looked like:

```
gem install tilt   -v 1.3.3
gem install execjs -v 1.2.4
gem install temple -v 0.3.3
gem install guard  -v 0.6.3
gem install guard-livereload -v 0.3.1
gem install rack-cache -v 1.0.3
```

I think that `gem pristine xxx yyy zzz` or `gem pristine --all` might not be going out always (ever?) to the gem repositories whereas `gem install xxx -v v.r.m` does.

Anyway, re-installing the offending versions of the gems worked for me, although it was tedious...

Answer (score 1):

`rvm gemset clear` and then `bundle install` worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

"gem install rubygems-update", "update_rubygems", then "gem pristine --all" is the combination that solved the problem for me after none of the previously listed ones worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the referenced gem versions weren't even installed. I had those gems, but not the versions who's gemspecs were causing the error. So, I just deleted each of the /path/to/specifications/offending-X.Y.ZZ.gemspec files.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer but if somebody feels like digging more I found this gemspec spec here: http://rubygems.rubyforge.org/rubygems-update/Gem/Specification.html (scroll down to date=date() and click to show source):

```
@date = case date
when String then
  if %r\A(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\Z/ =~ date then
    Time.utc($1.to_i, $2.to_i, $3.to_i)
  else
    raise(Gem::InvalidSpecificationException,
          "invalid date format in specification: #{date.inspect}")
  end
when Time, Date then
  Time.utc(date.year, date.month, date.day)
else
  TODAY
end
```

So I guess this is the code that parses that gemspec, and it just looks like the date format that are in the files that show errors don't conform to this.

What I did was to just manually fix those offending gemspecs as suggested above (changing the dates to "yyyy-mm-dd", it works for me.

All the rubygem specs I had that had this problem also has a line

s.rubygems_version = %q{1.3.5}

So I'm guessing these are just old gems? And what's with those %q{...} anyway?

Answer (score 0):

If you had this error on Ubuntu 11.04 my solution was the following command lines:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1
```

After doing this you will not get the date error.