# invalid date format in specification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Invalid date format specification in gemspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290575/invalid-date-format-specification-in-gemspec)

I am beginner in ruby on rails. When I try `gem list` it displays message below:

```
Invalid gemspec in [/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications/rack-protection-1.1.2.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-10-01 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications/whenever-0.7.0.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-09-02 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications/chronic-0.6.4.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-09-09 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications/uuid-2.3.4.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-09-02 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications/tilt-1.3.3.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-08-25 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications/sinatra-1.3.0.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-10-01 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications/rack-cache-1.0.3.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-08-27 00:00:00.000000000Z"
```

When I try to run script/server or rake -T it still shows the same message.

Comment: Check out the answers to a similar question asked a few months back:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771758/invalid-gemspec-because-of-the-date-format-in-specification For me, the solution in the first answer worked. Hope it helps!

Comment: I was on Ubuntu 11.10. I also used the above thread to solve the problem but instead of the first answer I used the one that recommended:
    `sudo gem install rubygems-update;
    sudo update_rubygems`