# Invalid gemspec error while running compass in ruby

Tags: ruby, compass-sass

I receive the following error when running a new compass project in OSX 10.7.3.

```
Invalid gemspec in [/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/specifications/multipart-post-1.1.5.gemspec]:           invalid date format in specification: "2012-02-13 00:00:00.000000000Z"
```

I have tried running sudo gem update --system to cure the problem but I get the same error when doing so.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invalid gemspec because of the date format in specification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771758/invalid-gemspec-because-of-the-date-format-in-specification)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
gem install rubygems-update
update_rubygems
```

You may also find this helpful esp. the answer of GaborKomaromi

[Invalid date format specification in gemspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290575/invalid-date-format-specification-in-gemspec)

Comment: Invalid gemspec in [/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/specifications/multipart-post-1.1.5.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2012-02-13 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/specifications/multipart-post-1.1.5.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2012-02-13 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/specifications/multipart-post-1.1.5.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2012-02-13 00:00:00.000000000Z"
RubyGems 1.8.21 installed

Comment: you may try deleting 00:00:00.000000000Z in the gemspec file.

Comment: I was able to find the solution here which is similar to yours. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771758/invalid-gemspec-because-of-the-date-format-in-specification. Thank you!