# Who can help me install and get RubyGems working on Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm having trouble installing RubyGems on my Mac OS X Lion operating system.

I get all sorts of errors saying invalid date specification.

Please help, and thanks in advance!

/Lasse

Comment: Can you post your error messages  you can use https://gist.github.com/  to post error  messages or code snippets

Comment: Sure – https://gist.github.com/2350304 – thanks in advance!

Comment: Why does the RubyGems suddenly don't work? Is it due to some update of the RubyGems command? Now suddenly RubyGems work but when installing Rails 3.2.3 it doesn't include any dependencies :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing Command Line Tools from Xcode > Preferences > Downloads solved the problem, and I can now use RubyGems and Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 1):

do you use [rvm](http://beginrescueend.com/) to administrate your gems? if not i approve to use it.

With Rvm it is easy to manage  your ruby versions and with it you can install rubygems without any problems:

additionally i found some answers to your "Invalid gemspec" error:

- [So 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077894/invalid-gemspec-error-while-running-compass-in-ruby)
- [So 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771758/invalid-gemspec-because-of-the-date-format-in-specification)

but i recommend you to use Rvm to install rubygems

Comment: You need to install a C compiler to build Ruby. It's probably simplest to install [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/).

Comment: try to install ruby with gcc clang  rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang or rvm install 1.9.2 --with-gcc=clang

Comment: @Brandan: Why is this necessary?

Comment: Because osx does not get a gcc compiler and  the installation for many gems need one you can use xcode or the osx-gcc-installer (xcode is free aviable in the appstore)

Comment: Some of Ruby is written in C, so of you're building from source code (as rvm does), you need a C compiler.