# error while running any gem commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Whenever I try using any gem operations from the command line I get this error before it executes the operation. Currently I received this while running heroku commands, however the heroku commands did run successfully after the below error was displayed. How do I get rid of the below error display -

```
Invalid gemspec in [/home/murtaza/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/specifications/mail-2.3.3.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2012-03-14 00:00:00.000000000Z" Invalid gemspec in [/home/murtaza/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/specifications/jquery-rails-1.0.19.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-11-26 00:00:00.000000000Z" Invalid gemspec in [/home/murtaza/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/specifications/multipart-post-1.1.5.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2012-02-13 00:00:00.000000000Z" Invalid gemspec in [/home/murtaza/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/specifications/uuid-2.3.5.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2012-01-23 00:00:00.000000000Z" Invalid gemspec in [/home/murtaza/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/specifications/oauth2-0.5.2.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2012-01-04 00:00:00.000000000Z" Invalid gemspec in [/home/murtaza/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/specifications/rack-cache-1.0.3.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-08-27 00:00:00.000000000Z"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290575/invalid-date-format-specification-in-gemspec

Comment: @ShreyasAgarwal Don't just put a link to the duplicate - also vote to close the question as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks Shreyas. gem-pristine -all solved it.

Answer (score 2):

gem-pristine -all solved the problem !