# WARNING: Invalid .gemspec format in '/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/specifications/rack-1.3.5.gemspec'

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gemspecs

I am trying to run a Sinatra app, and am failing because rack isn't being found.
I am getting the following error:

```
WARNING:  Invalid .gemspec format in '/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/specifications/rack-1.3.5.gemspec'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:636:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem rack (~> 1.3, >= 1.3.4) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:141:in `activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:165:in `activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:164:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:164:in `activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
```

I am running Ruby version 1.8.6

I have tried deleting the gemspec file and running gem install again. When I install rack it succeeds without error.

Comment: Follow the instructions here to fix it.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771758/invalid-gemspec-because-of-the-date-format-in-specification

Answer (score 2):

Try to update your rubygem package

gem update --system

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this `gem update --system` ?