# rails 3.2.0 and heroku

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, activemodel

I have some troubles with rails 3.2.0 & ruby 1.9.3, I only created a new app with rails new command and I'm trying to deploy to heroku. I'm having the following app error:

**An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.
If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.**

After run **heroku logs** I get the following error:

**Could not find activemodel-3.2.0 in any of the sources**

Thanks in advance!!!!

GemFile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
```

Gemfile.lock file

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.0)
      actionpack (= 3.2.0)
      mail (~> 2.4.0)
    actionpack (3.2.0)
      activemodel (= 3.2.0)
      activesupport (= 3.2.0)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.0)
      rack (~> 1.4.0)
      rack-cache (~> 1.1)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.1.2)
    activemodel (3.2.0)
      activesupport (= 3.2.0)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.0)
      activemodel (= 3.2.0)
      activesupport (= 3.2.0)
      arel (~> 3.0.0)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.0)
      activemodel (= 3.2.0)
      activesupport (= 3.2.0)
    activesupport (3.2.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    arel (3.0.0)
    builder (3.0.0)
    coffee-rails (3.2.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0.beta)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.2.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (1.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    hike (1.2.1)
    i18n (0.6.0)
    journey (1.0.0)
    jquery-rails (2.0.0)
      railties (>= 3.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    json (1.6.5)
    mail (2.4.1)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.17.2)
    multi_json (1.0.4)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.4.0)
    rack-cache (1.1)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-ssl (1.3.2)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.0)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.0)
      actionpack (= 3.2.0)
      activerecord (= 3.2.0)
      activeresource (= 3.2.0)
      activesupport (= 3.2.0)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.0)
    railties (3.2.0)
      actionpack (= 3.2.0)
      activesupport (= 3.2.0)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (~> 0.14.6)
    rake (0.9.2.2)
    rdoc (3.12)
      json (~> 1.4)
    sass (3.1.12)
    sass-rails (3.2.3)
      railties (~> 3.2.0.beta)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    sprockets (2.1.2)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.5)
    thor (0.14.6)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    treetop (1.4.10)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.31)
    uglifier (1.2.2)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.0.2)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1)
  jquery-rails
  rails (= 3.2.0)
  sass-rails (~> 3.2.3)
  sqlite3
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
```

Comment: What does your `Gemfile` look like?

Comment: can you paste all references to activemodel from Gemfile.lock please?

Comment: ps - [forem](https://github.com/radar/forem.heroku.com) runs on 3.2 on heroku so I'm guessing this can be done

Comment: added Gemfile.lock, Im trying for downgrade rails but rails executable stills reference to 3.2 and cant run rails:(, Thanks!!!

Comment: I downgrading ok, the prob was i were on old app directory:P Thanks!

Comment: Here's a detailed tutorial that shows how to set up Ruby 1.9.3 on Heroku: [Using Rails 3.2 and Ruby 1.9.3 on Heroku](http://railsapps.github.com/rails-heroku-tutorial.html) It covers deploying an app to Heroku in depth.

Answer (score 7):

Rails 3.2 applications run fine on Cedar, I've just upgraded several applications to run on Cedar and are running on Heroku. Once you've updated your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock make sure you commit them both and push them both to Heroku. Heroku will then rebundle your application to use Rails 3.2.

Incidentally, I don't specify any version numbers on sass-rails or uglifier in my Gemfiles.

Of course, you can test in production mode running locally before you push to Heroku to see if it's going to work.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I had this same problem *not* on Heroku, but on one of our local deployment servers. We were running on a server with Ruby `1.8.7-p72`. RubyGems was shamefully out of date — it had `v1.3.7` on it. Running a `gem update --system` to bump it up to `v1.8.15`, and then redeploying, worked like a charm (despite all the `invalid gemspec` warnings we received in the log).

Not specific to Heroku, but hopefully helpful to any Googlers that come wandering in here like I did.

Comment: Thanks found a bunch of Heroku references but nothing on managed servers. Your solution solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks! [This perl one-liner](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8181215/194869) fixed all the gemspec errors in a pinch, too. Painless!

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar problem today. After creating and pushing a new app, heroku said "Could not find multi_json-1.3.1 in any of the sources"

This is how I solved it:

1. Delete local Gemfile.lock
2. Run bundle install
3. Push again => Everything works well

Answer (score 1):

Check the stack by using `heroku stack`. Your app might not be on 'cedar' stack. I had the same issue and re-creating the app on 'cedar' resolved the issue.

Comment: this was my problem, i was on bamboo.

Answer (score 0):

I used latest Rails from "3-2-stable" and the problem has also gone.

Answer (score -1):

upgrade to rc2 and it should fix it

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.0.rc2'
```

Comment: the OP is using Rails 3.2 (final) which was released on Friday.

Answer (score -7):

Heroku only supports up to Rails 3.1 (cedar stack).

Comment: I'm trying to downgrade from 3.2 to 3.1,and I get "Could not find railties-3.2.0 in any of the sources", can anyone helps me on that! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: To downgrade, make sure you run `bundle install` after you change the versions back to their original `3.1.x` versions.

Comment: Simply not true - Heroku is not bound to any particular version of Rails

Comment: @Neil-Middleton Only cedar stack supports the asset pipeline (http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar) so in that sense, it does matter which stack you use.  I haven't found anywhere that cedar stack officially supports 3.2.

Comment: Cedar doesn't officially support anything as it's not yet GA.  I have numerous apps running 3.2 on Cedar right now.